# javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

Node unable to join cluster with the below error. Below is the ulimit set. Please help me to resolve the error.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 10240
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256573
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 250000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32768
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Nodetool error

```
error: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy
-- StackTrace --
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageProxy
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:643)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.getAttribute(MBeanServerAccessController.java:320)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1445)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

System.log

````
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/xx.xx.xx.xx] 2023-08-28 16:58:37,168 StreamSession.java:524 - [Stream #abe86ee0-45c3-11ee-a097-7147fb5b55a2] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /data/cassandra/keyspace/table-data-8a362f90d88f11e89c4f6f2fad1ea73b/tmp-lb-184-big-Index.db: Too many open files
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.<init>(SequentialWriter.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open(SequentialWriter.java:155) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$IndexWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:467) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.19.jar:2.2.19]
    ```
````

Comment: Which _user_ are those resource limits set for?  Needs to be set for the specific user that Cassandra runs as.